# Anyone know why this method for linked list keeps on going forever?

Tags: java, arrays, function, methods, linked-list

I have this linked list method that is used to insert before, so it takes a node and puts it before the beforeNode. Currently it does that, but then it goes on forever and makes the linked list infinitely big when it should only be four long. Does anyone see why it keeps on going?

```
private void insertBefore(Node aNode, Node beforeNode)
    {

        if(this.getPrevious(beforeNode) != null) {
            this.getPrevious(beforeNode).setNext(aNode);
           // aNode.setPrevious(beforeNode);
            //this.getPrevious(this.getPrevious(beforeNode)).setNext(aNode);
        } else {
            head = aNode;
        }
        aNode.setNext(beforeNode);
       // beforeNode.setPrevious(aNode);

    }
```

Here is the print list method that could have something to do with it, but I dont think so

```
 public void printList()
    {
        Node currentNode;

        currentNode = this.getHead();

        System.out.print("head ->");

        while(currentNode!=null)
        {
            System.out.print(currentNode.getData().toString()+ " -> ");
            currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
        }
        System.out.println("|||");
    }
```

Comment: Is something calling it repeatedly? What does beforeNode do? You don't have a while loop, so it could be called recursively by something else. I also don't see anything that would make it 4 long.

Comment: It's for sure something is calling insertBefore repatedly.

Comment: @Jack I use it in the main like this myLinkedList.insertBefore(myNode4, myNode2);

Comment: @nhgrif setNext is not the issue, that was given to me by professor, so far it has worked fine for other things. I also do check the one prior to before node to make sure it is not null

Comment: @hasan I dont think so because when I change the end of the function to : if(aNode.getNext()!=null){
      aNode.setNext(beforeNode);
     } it doesnt go on forever, but 2 of the nodes get deleted somehow

Comment: The problem can't be this method. There's no loop and no recursive call. Look at the other methods too.

Comment: @Radiodef I put the printlist() method on there which is the only thing it could possibly be, but I dont think it is, because depending on how I edit the insertBefore() method it either doesnt work and only prints out a few, or it works and goes on forever

Comment: My guess is there is some kind of interaction and one of the methods called in insertBefore calls insertBefore under some condition. Do you get an exception with a trace you can follow through? It just freezes? What is the indication there is a problem?

Comment: I agree with @Radiodef, and I think we're really going to need to see more code for this to be diagnosed by someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I think some how you are passing the same node for both aNode and beforeNode.  In java, every object is a reference.  Did you by any chance try to create aNode a copy of beforeNode ?  It might have made both the same and causing the linked list to have a self loop.  use a copy constructor or things like clone to get a duplicate node.